# Individual-level factor as predictor in `mediate` command for multilevel models

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, mediation

I want to run a multilevel mediation model by fitting `lmer` models and feeding them to the `mediate` function in the `mediation` package. Say I have typical repeated-measures data from an experiment with two conditions per participant, and each condition has five measures.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- 
  tibble(
    group = factor(paste("id_", rep(1:5, each = 10))),
    condition = factor(rep(c("control", "treatment"), 25)),
    mediator = rnorm(50),
    outcome = rnorm(50)
  )
```

Then I follow the documentation and fit the model predicting the mediator and the model predicting the outcome. I follow a maximal effects structure, with a slope for each predictor.

```
# sum-to-zero contrasts
options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))

# model predicting mediator
med_fit <- 
  lme4::lmer(
    mediator ~
      condition +
      (1 + condition | group),
    dat
  )

# model predicting outcome
med_out <- 
  lme4::lmer(
    outcome ~
      condition + mediator +
      (1 + condition + mediator | group),
    dat
  )
```

Now, when I feed those two models to the `mediate` command, I get an error message.

```
mediation_fit <- 
  mediation::mediate(
    med_fit,
    med_out,
    treat = "condition",
    mediator = "mediator",
    treat.value = "treatment",
    control.value = "control"
  )

Error in `[.data.frame`(m.data, , treat) : undefined columns selected
```

If I transform `condition` into numeric, the mediation model works. Can someone explain why that is? Does the `mediation` package not support individual-level predictors as factors?

Comment: PS: First time posting here, please let me know if this belongs to Stackoverflow and not here.

Comment: You might do better on the R mailing list dedicated to mixed models if nobody answers here.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same. Thanks, @mdewey.